# Debugging monit

Tags: debugging, shell, monit

I find debugging monit to be a major pain. Monit's shell environment basically has nothing in it (no paths or other environment variables). Also, there are no log file that I can find.

The problem is, if the start or stop command in the monit script fails, it is difficult to discern what is wrong with it. Often times it is not as simple as just running the command on the shell because the shell environment is different from the monit shell environment.

What are some techniques that people use to debug monit configurations?

For example, I would be happy to have a monit shell, to test my scripts in, or a log file to see what went wrong.

Comment: I did find that monit has logging facilities. http://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html

Unfortunately, it's not as detail as I would like.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

I've had the same problem. Using monit's verbose command-line option helps a bit, but I found the best way was to create an environment as similar as possible to the monit environment and run the start/stop program from there.

```
# monit runs as superuser
$ sudo su

# the -i option ignores the inherited environment
# this PATH is what monit supplies by default
$ env -i PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin /bin/sh

# try running start/stop program here
$
```

I've found the most common problems are environment variable related (especially `PATH`) or permission-related. You should remember that monit usually runs as root.

Also if you use `as uid myusername` in your monit config, then you should change to user `myusername` before carrying out the test.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful.  But how do you change to myusername without pulling in their environment too?

Comment: @Chocohound $ sudo myusername; $ env -i PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin /bin/sh

Comment: @s01ipsist this should be `su myusername`

Comment: this is a great tip, in general

Comment: This still didn't do for me, script remained running fine when executing from that environment and not when called from monit. @thodg solution helped me though. Monit really needs to add documentation on this.

Answer (score 39):

Be sure to always double check your conf and monitor your processes by hand before letting monit handle everything. systat(1), top(1) and ps(1) are your friends to figure out resource usage and limits. Knowing the process you monitor is essential too.

Regarding the start and stop scripts i use a wrapper script to redirect output and inspect environment and other variables. Something like this :

```
$ cat monit-wrapper.sh

#!/bin/sh
{
  echo "MONIT-WRAPPER date"
  date
  echo "MONIT-WRAPPER env"
  env
  echo "MONIT-WRAPPER $@"
  $@
  R=$?
  echo "MONIT-WRAPPER exit code $R"
} >/tmp/monit.log 2>&1
```

Then in monit :

```
start program = "/home/billitch/bin/monit-wrapper.sh my-real-start-script and args"
stop program = "/home/billitch/bin/monit-wrapper.sh my-real-stop-script and args"
```

You still have to figure out what infos you want in the wrapper, like process infos, id, system resources limits, etc.

Comment: The very excellent thing about @billitch monit-wrapper is that the resultant log file **actually includes the error message** that is causing your problem (eg. can't find an executable) that monit swallows up.  A very good suggestion and has saved me a whole heap of pain.

Comment: i had to use `start program=/bin/bash -c "..."`

Comment: This one was of great help. Nothing I had tried showed anything that could be the culprit between script failing when run through monit, and always working when I was in Terminal(as in other suggestions in here). Script worked when running through your script and seems like, for some reason, the way I was trying to pipe output and if I was piping output was the culprit. Script would execute and exit immediately and the program I was starting would disappear with it, changing my script to pipe out like in this wrapper made it work (?)

Answer (score 15):

You can start Monit in verbose/debug mode by adding `MONIT_OPTS="-v"` to `/etc/default/monit` (don't forget to restart; `/etc/init.d/monit restart`).

You can then capture the output using `tail -f /var/log/monit.log`

```
[CEST Jun  4 21:10:42] info     : Starting Monit 5.17.1 daemon with http interface at [*]:2812
[CEST Jun  4 21:10:42] info     : Starting Monit HTTP server at [*]:2812
[CEST Jun  4 21:10:42] info     : Monit HTTP server started
[CEST Jun  4 21:10:42] info     : 'ocean' Monit 5.17.1 started
[CEST Jun  4 21:10:42] debug    : Sending Monit instance changed notification to monit@example.io
[CEST Jun  4 21:10:42] debug    : Trying to send mail via smtp.sendgrid.net:587
[CEST Jun  4 21:10:43] debug    : Processing postponed events queue
[CEST Jun  4 21:10:43] debug    : 'rootfs' succeeded getting filesystem statistics for '/'
[CEST Jun  4 21:10:43] debug    : 'rootfs' filesytem flags has not changed
[CEST Jun  4 21:10:43] debug    : 'rootfs' inode usage test succeeded [current inode usage=8.5%]
[CEST Jun  4 21:10:43] debug    : 'rootfs' space usage test succeeded [current space usage=59.6%]
[CEST Jun  4 21:10:43] debug    : 'ws.example.com' succeeded testing protocol [WEBSOCKET] at [ws.example.com]:80/faye [TCP/IP] [response time 114.070 ms]
[CEST Jun  4 21:10:43] debug    : 'ws.example.com' connection succeeded to [ws.example.com]:80/faye [TCP/IP]
```

Answer (score 10):

`monit -c /path/to/your/config -v`

Answer (score 5):

By default, monit logs to your system message log and you can check there to see what's happening.

Also, depending on your config, you might be logging to a different place

```
tail -f /var/log/monit
```

http://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#LOGGING

Assuming defaults (as of whatever old version of monit I'm using), you can tail the logs as such:

**CentOS:**

```
tail -f /var/log/messages
```

**Ubuntu:**

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

**Mac OSX**

```
tail -f /var/log/system.log
```

**Windows**

Here be Dragons

But there is a neato project I found while searching on how to do this out of morbid curiosity: https://github.com/derFunk/monit-windows-agent

Comment: I don't see this file on my monit setup.

Comment: You're on a UNIX machine? /var/log/messages is a standard place for system logging on a lot of UNIX machines.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.  I've fixed my monit questions, though... Weird either way that I don't have it...

Comment: Not entirely. Each UNIX distro can log standard messages wherever the developers choose.

Apparently, ubuntu logs to `/var/log/syslog`

[where is var/log/messages?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/51265/where-is-var-log-messages)

Comment: RHL and centos is tail-f /var/log/monit

Answer (score 2):

Yeah monit isn't too easy to debug.

Here a few best practices

- use a wrapper script that sets up your log file.  Write your command arguments in there while you are at it:

shell:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

logfile=/var/log/myjob.log
touch ${logfile} 
echo $$ ": ################# Starting " $(date) "########### pid " $$ >> ${logfile}

echo "Command: the-command $@" >> ${logfile} # log your command arguments
{
  exec the-command $@
} >> ${logfile} 2>&1
```

That helps a lot.

The other thing I find that helps is to run monit with '-v', which gives you verbosity.  So the workflow is

- get your wrapper working from the shell "sudo my-wrapper"
- then try and get it going from monit, run from the command line with "-v"
- then try and get it going from monit, running in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try running monit validate once processes are running, to try and find out if any of them are having problems (and sometimes get more information than you would get in the log files if there are any problems). Beyond that, there's not much more you can do.