# Node.js (sudo) and monit

Tags: node.js, monit

I have created an upstart script in order to daemonize juggernaut (a node.js app)
The upstart script is the following

```
description "juggernaut server"
author      "panojsee"

start on startup
stop on shutdown

script
    # We found $HOME is needed. Without it, we ran into problems
    #export HOME="/home/ubuntu/src/juggernaut"
    chdir /home/ubuntu/src/juggernaut
    exec sudo /usr/bin/node server.js 2>&1 >> /var/log/node.log
end script
```

As you can see I want to run node with sudo (so that I can use Flash sockets). 
My monit script is the following:

set logfile /var/log/monit.log

```
check host juggernaut with address 127.0.0.1
    start program = "/sbin/start juggernaut"
    stop program  = "/sbin/stop juggernaut"
    if failed port 8080 protocol HTTP
        request /
        with timeout 10 seconds
        then restart
```

Monit does not allow me to have start program = "**sudo** /sbin/start juggernaut"
Once I kill juggernaut (node) then monit tries to restart it but dies with the following message.

```
[UTC Feb  3 22:48:25] error    : 'nodejs' failed, cannot open a connection to INET[127.0.0.1:8080] via TCP
[UTC Feb  3 22:48:25] info     : 'nodejs' trying to restart
[UTC Feb  3 22:48:25] info     : 'nodejs' stop: sudo
[UTC Feb  3 22:48:25] error    : Error: Could not execute sudo
[UTC Feb  3 22:48:25] info     : 'nodejs' start: sudo
```

Any clue how can I tell monit to execute a sudo command ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just start Monit with sudo and of course add monit to sudoers

Answer (score 3):

I think you should run nodeJS with dedicated user then remove "exec sudo" from the starting script, and tell monit directly which user you would like to use.

> start program = "/sbin/start juggernaut" as uid user-id

Answer (score 1):

Check what user monit is running as. Is that user configured to run sudo? Check also if sudo has reported any errors (probably in `/var/log/messages`).

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356476/debugging-monit/4439403#4439403) to be very helpful in figuring out monit behavior.