# Restart ffmpeg process using monit if TOTAL CPU is less than 1%

Tags: linux, shell, ffmpeg, monitoring, monit

I have used kind of similar solution like this [Restarting ffmpeg process using monit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36128450/restarting-ffmpeg-process-using-monit/41274415) to restart my ffmpeg stream in case it fails for some reason. Remember its not duplicate problem/question, because I have other issues unlike the example question/solution [Restarting ffmpeg process using monit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36128450/restarting-ffmpeg-process-using-monit/41274415), which I'm gonna explain below. So here is my monit configuration:

```
    check process FFMPEGStream with pidfile PATH-to-file/streampid.pid
    start program = "PATH-to-file/streambash.sh restart"
    stop program = "PATH-to-file/streambash.sh stop"
    if TOTAL CPU is less than 1% for 10 cycles then restart
```

Here is my streambash.sh file:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    pid_file="PATH-to-file/streampid.pid"

    case "$1" in
     restart)
        PATH-to-file/streambash.sh stop
        PATH-to-file/streambash.sh start
           ;;

     start)
        rm $pid_file
        /usr/bin/ffmpeg -i "INPUT-PATH" -c:v libx264 -b:v 900k -preset ultrafast -aspect 16:9 -s 640x376 -strict experimental -c:a aac -b:a 96k -f flv "RTMP-PATH" &> /dev/null &
        ch_pid=$! 
        echo "Start Stream1: ffmpeg = $ch_pid";
        echo $ch_pid > $pid_file
           ;;

     stop)
        echo "Stop ffmpeg Stream1";
        kill `cat $pid_file` &> /dev/null
           ;;

     *)
        echo "Usage: PATH-to-file/streambash.sh {start|stop|restart}"
        exit 1
           ;;

     esac
    exit 0
    echo $pid_file
```

Monit can start the bash file successfully, but when this condition *"if TOTAL CPU is less than 1% for 10 cycles then restart"* is matched in monit configuration, it tries to restart, it gives error that process is not running. But in actual the ffmpeg process still runs in the background and I can see that the stream is live on my website. Here is monit logs:

```
    [CET Jan 10 12:55:02] error    : 'FFMPEGStream' total cpu usage of 0.4% matches resource limit [cpu usage>1.0%]
    [CET Jan 10 12:55:07] error    : 'FFMPEGStream' total cpu usage of 0.0% matches resource limit [cpu usage>1.0%]
    [CET Jan 10 12:55:12] error    : 'FFMPEGStream' total cpu usage of 0.0% matches resource limit [cpu usage>1.0%]
    [CET Jan 10 12:55:17] error    : 'FFMPEGStream' total cpu usage of 0.4% matches resource limit [cpu usage>1.0%]
    [CET Jan 10 12:55:22] error    : 'FFMPEGStream' total cpu usage of 0.9% matches resource limit [cpu usage>1.0%]
    [CET Jan 10 12:55:27] error    : 'FFMPEGStream' total cpu usage of 0.9% matches resource limit [cpu usage>1.0%]
    [CET Jan 10 12:55:32] error    : 'FFMPEGStream' total cpu usage of 0.0% matches resource limit [cpu usage>1.0%]
    [CET Jan 10 12:55:37] error    : 'FFMPEGStream' total cpu usage of 0.0% matches resource limit [cpu usage>1.0%]
    [CET Jan 10 12:55:42] error    : 'FFMPEGStream' total cpu usage of 0.0% matches resource limit [cpu usage>1.0%]
    [CET Jan 10 12:55:47] error    : 'FFMPEGStream' total cpu usage of 0.4% matches resource limit [cpu usage>1.0%]
    [CET Jan 10 12:55:50] info     : 'FFMPEGStream' trying to restart
    [CET Jan 10 12:55:50] info     : 'FFMPEGStream' stop: PATH-to-file/streambash.sh
    [CET Jan 10 12:55:51] info     : 'FFMPEGStream' start: PATH-to-file/streambash.sh
    [CET Jan 10 12:55:56] error    : 'FFMPEGStream' process is not running
    [CET Jan 10 12:55:58] info     : 'FFMPEGStream' trying to restart
    [CET Jan 10 12:55:58] info     : 'FFMPEGStream' start: PATH-to-file/streambash.sh
    [CET Jan 10 12:56:04] error    : 'FFMPEGStream' process is not running
    [CET Jan 10 12:56:04] info     : 'FFMPEGStream' trying to restart
    [CET Jan 10 12:56:04] info     : 'FFMPEGStream' start: PATH-to-file/streambash.sh
    [CET Jan 10 12:56:09] error    : 'FFMPEGStream' process is not running
    [CET Jan 10 12:56:09] info     : 'FFMPEGStream' trying to restart
    [CET Jan 10 12:56:09] info     : 'FFMPEGStream' start: PATH-to-file/streambash.sh
```

Monit keeps trying to restart the process and on each retry, it dumps a new pid to the PATH-to-file/streampid.pid, but as I said it seems, it somehow can stop the actual ffmpeg stream/pid, which keep running in the background.

Comment: Why don't use nice or cgroups?

Comment: My problem is not CPU handling, my problem is process is not restarted or atleast not shown as started in monit if after its not running. CPU usage is just a way that I used to know that the process is not working or ffmpeg is encoding or any related problem. So doesn't make sense to use nice or cgroups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your poll cycle / daemon check interval is very low, 5 seconds?

FFMpeg isn't starting within 5 seconds so monit tries to start it again, constantly in a loop.

If you want to have such a low check interval, you need to set a timeout on the start command, along the lines of:

```
start program = "PATH-to-file/streambash.sh restart" with timeout 30 seconds
```

This really helps me to understand monit's way of thinking, watch the live log in a terminal window while monit is doing things:

```
 tail -f /var/log/monit.log
```

Comment: Another thing, monit / monit webif is very slow to detect and update cpu usage on a recently started process. Be patient and give it a minute or more! Even thoguh the process started and is using e.g., 10% CPU, monit webif states that the process is still using 0% and restarts the process, in a sometimes never ending loop.